# Comparing dictionaries and then appending them if true?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 3 dictionaries that contain the scores for a students hw, quiz, and exam scores, however, I need to put these three dictionaries into a super dictionary with all the students scores in the them with the following structure.

"123-45-6789":{"hw":[98,89,92,75], "quiz":[45,36,42,50,29,27,40,41], "exam":[175,157]}

I tried making a default dictionary with all the student ids as keys and then empty values, but I'm not too familiar with how to manipulate dictionaries appropriately, so that if a key were to be found to add the dictionary into the super dictionary

Here is some of the code I have that converted 3 texts file into 3 dictionaies

```
def create_dictionary():
    fullRoster= dict()
    idList= []
    quizList= []
    hwList= []
    examList= []
    studentids= open("studentids.txt", "r")
    idList= [line.rstrip()for line in studentids]
    studentids.close()
    idList= dict.fromkeys(idList)
    #hwFile converted into a list and then into a dictionary
    #the exam and homework files follow the same structure
    hwFile= open("hwscores.txt", "r")
    hwList= [line.rstrip().split() for line in hwFile]
    hwFile.close()
    #searches for similar ids then places quiz score into single list
    for i in range (15):
        for k in range ((len(hwList))):
            if hwList[i][0]== hwList[k][0] and i!=k:
                hwList[i].append((hwList[k][1]))
    hwList= hwList[:15]
    #adds zero if hw list is not 5
    for i in range (15):
        if len(hwList[i])!=5:
            while len(hwList[i])<5:
                hwList[i].append(0)
    #dictionary comprehension to create dictionary
    hwList= {l[0]: [int(x) for x in l[1:]] for l in hwList}
```

Comment: What is format of each of the input files? Can you mention that in question?

Comment: To check whether key is present in dictionary, you can use something like `if 'student_id' in student_id_dict.keys()`. If key present then you can append the value to the existing list else you can create a new key-value pair.

Comment: @RohanSadale the files are a dump of all the student ids with one score next to them like this: 
709-40-8165 168
560-33-3099 176
503-27-1729 194
267-10-7633 142
807-49-0073 82

Comment: You say you have *3 dictionaries which contain the scores for a students hw, quiz, and exam scores* and in the comments that this is stored with the key as their id and a single scalar value. This would be impossible as you describe it, as dictionaries must have unique keys, so I think you first need to clean up your question and put in a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are trying to do with a set of example data as it should look when loaded from the file. As any answer now will basically be someone doing all the work for you.

Comment: @EttyEts what is the format of hwscores.txt?

Comment: @JGreenwell Prompt: 
A function called create dictionary with four parameters: idfilename, hwfilename,
qzfilename, and examfilename. These parameters are, respectively, the names of the
files containing student IDs, homework scores, quiz scores, and exam scores.This
function returns a dictionary of key:value pairs in which the key is the student ID
and the value is itself a dictionary containing the keys "hw", "quiz", and "exam". The
values associated with these keys are lists of length 4, 8, and 2 containing, respectively,
the homework, quiz, and exam score data for that student.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k in fullRoster:
    fullRoster[k] = {'hw':hwList[k], 'quiz':quizList[k], 'exam':examList[k]}
```

Turns out this was all i had to do as this for loop with fullRoster being a dictionary of the studentids as the keys and the values an empty dictionary itself, the loop iterates through finding the appropriate matching id then adds it.

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.